# sort list of int[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I would like to sort a list of int arrays in java, specifically like so:

```
1, 2
1, 3
2, 3
1, 4
2, 4
3, 1
```

Should be sorted into:

```
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 3
2, 4
3, 1
```

I read some other posts, and have been trying to use something like this that was answered for sorting `String[]`:

```
Collections.sort(listOfStringArrays,new Comparator<String[]>() {
        public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
            return strings[1].compareTo(otherStrings[1]);
        }
    });
```

by changing it into:

```
Collections.sort(listOfIntArrays,new Comparator<int[]>() {
        public int compare(int[] ints, int[] otherInts) {
            return ints[0].compareTo(otherInts[0]);
        }
    });
```

But this didn't work, the error was for the return line `Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int`

Can someone help me.

Comment: To be clear, it's actually a `String[]` and not two `int[]`?

Comment: You can compare `int`s directly via `<`, `<=`, `==`. `>=` and `>`. Also, you porbably want to first sort by the 1st element ant if those are equal sort by the 2nd element. For the specifics as to when to return what, take a look at [the correspondig Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: @4castle It's two `int[]`, the `String[]` code was what I found on this site on another post, and have been trying to change it so that it works for `int[]`. @Turing85 How would I be able to do that? I am fairly new to Java, have been trying to read more documentations but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @CConard96 that would over-engineered and slow due to [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal that you get this error since the `.compareTo(Integer)` method can only be called from an `Integer` object. But in your case, you have primitive `int` elements.

To make your comparison work, you can call the `Integer.compare(int, int)` method instead like this:

Instead of

```
return ints[0].compareTo(otherInts[0]);
```

Use

```
return Integer.compare(ints[0], otherInts[0]);
```

You can take a look at [Integer#compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) method description

#### Sorting depending on both values

If you want to sort both on first and second value, you can simply transform the two values into one by creating a two digit number (assuming that each value is a digit in the range 0-9).

I suggest you to do like this

```
return Integer.compare(ints[0] * 10 + ints[1], otherInts[0] * 10 + otherInts[1]);
```

Comment: I like this much better than my suggestion to convert to an Integer array. +1

Comment: You probably want to compare `ints[0]` with `otherInts[0]`since you want to sort by the first element, not the second.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, I just edited my question with a note and corrected that part. I wanted to sort by the first field.

Comment: With this solution, it sorts the `int[]` based on the first field, but now the second. Is it at all possible that it sorts based on both fields together?

Comment: @gptt916 yes it is. You need some more logic within the `Comparator`. See [my original comment for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401782/sort-list-of-int-in-java/37401861?noredirect=1#comment62312057_37401782).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, works great. @Turing85 I will be reading that today as well to understand the `Comparator` better.

Answer (score 1):

As @tfosra said, you should use `Integer.compare(int, int)` instead. However, I suggest using a different method for prioritizing the first array over the second array when sorting. If the first array contains equal values, compare the values in the second array. This won't constrict the range to 0-9, and is probably more readable.

```
return ints[0] != otherInts[0]
           ? Integer.compare(ints[0], otherInts[0])
           : Integer.compare(ints[1], otherInts[1]);
```

Comment: Exactly, this makes the solution more flexible